# Como puedo obtener en mi request el valor que se encuentra en el td Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-6

necesito ayuda con un problema, lo que sucede es que tengo un formulario que llamo de una tabla y no puedo enviar las preguntas que me vienen de mi tabla por el request  solo puedo enviar las respuestas,
en el ejemplo de mi código cuando el var_dump   en request->respuesta me arroja un array con las respuestas , de esta misma manera me gustario que el request->preguntas tenga las preguntas.

porfa si me pueden ayudar una ayuda de que puedo hacer.

aquí esta mi vista

```
<form   method="POST" action="{{route('resquestionario.insert')}}" id="resquestionario">
        @csrf
        <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Preguntas</th>
                                <th>Opciones</th>
                                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody> 
                            @foreach($questionario  as $pre)
                            <tr>
                                @if($pre->respuesta == 'texto')
                                <td  >{{$pre->pregunta}}</td>
                                    <label  name="pregunta[]"  >{{!!$pre->id!!}}</label>
                                    <br>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="respuesta[]" class="form-control" /></td>
                                @elseif($pre->respuesta == 'check')
                                <td name = "pregunta[]">{{$pre->pregunta}}</td>
                                @foreach(explode(',', $pre->opciones) as $info)

                                <td name="pregunta[]"><input type="checkbox" value="{{$info}}" name="respuesta[]" >{{$info}}</td>
                                @endforeach

                                @elseif($pre->respuesta =='radio buton')
                                <td  name="pregunta[]" pregunta[]>{{$pre->pregunta}}</td><br>
                                 <td><label for="respuestas">elige:</label>
                                <select id="respuesta" name="respuesta[]" >
                                @foreach(explode(',', $pre->opciones) as $info)
                                <option value="{{$info}}" >{{$info}}</option>
                                @endforeach

                                </select></td>
                                @endif

                            </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        </tbody>

                  <input type="submit" name="save" id ="sub{{ $pre->id }}" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
                    </table>
                    </form>
```

y mi controllador

```
public function insert(Request $request)
    {
        var_dump( $request->pregunta);
        var_dump($request->respuesta) ;
}
```

Comment: Lo más fácil sería que pongas también la pregunta en un input. Por ejemplo `<td><input type="text" name="pregunta[]" value="{{$pre->pregunta}}" readonly /></td>`

Comment: Complementando la respuesta de @porloscerrosΨ puedes usar el input de tipo hidden